# Unable to process the XML response from the server using jQuery and Ajax on my localhost?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have created a REST API which is returning data stored in the database in XML format.

When I run the code on my localhost the response is correct, but when I try to access the same link using Ajax and jQuery in the html page, I am unable to get any response or error messages.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#search").click(function(){
            fetch();
        });
    });
    function fetch(){
        var c=$("#description").val();
        $.ajax({
            url:"http://localhost:8085/lostandfound/webapi/lost/"+c,
            type:"GET",
            datatype:"XML",
            success:function(data){
                $("#result").children().remove();
                $(data).find("found").each(function(){
                    var info="<tr><td>name"+$(this).find("name").text()+"</td>  </tr>";
                    $("#result").append(info);
                });
            },
            error: function() {
                $('#output').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
            }
        });
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="addResultDiv" style="color: red"></div>
    <h2>search</h2>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <form id="userForm">
        <table id="result">
            <tr>
                <td>item:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="description" id="description"  />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="search" id="search" /></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="clear"  id="clear"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <div id="output">Search Result will Appear here!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make sure to type that last `div` tag correctly. It should not have a space after `<`.

Comment: Are you able to see the xml data in browser's page inspector while debugging?

Comment: yes when i access the link ,as specified in the restful webservice written in java ,using tomcat i am able to view xml data

Answer (score 0):

When the submit button is clicked, some JavaScript runs.

The JavaScript starts an Ajax request.

As soon as the JavaScript is done, the submit button does what submit buttons do. It submits the form. The browser loads a new page. The environment the Ajax request was running in *goes away*.

If you want the Ajax to work, then stop the normal behaviour of the submit button.

```
$("#search").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the input type from 'submit' to 'button'. This will not cause any page reloading.

`<input type="button" value="search" id="search" />`